# Access bounded form cannot be edited with code in afterupdate

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form(form A) that is bounded to a table and another table that is my master table(main table) with all the information. In form A, I have put a code in the after update for the field ID, this code queries the main table with the ID entered on the form and populates the other fields on the form, like name, gender, etc. When I do update the ID on the form to enter a record, the values that were queried are populating in the form but then it shows an error message on all the other fields which says,"Control cannot be edited,it's bound to an unknown field". I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me out with this?

```
Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT PERS_LNAME, PERS_FNAME, JOB_DETL_COLL_NAME, & _
        JOB_DETL_DEPT_NAME   FROM [main table] where ID = [Forms]![form A]![ID]"
    With Me
        .[Last Name].ControlSource = "PERS_LNAME"
        .[First Name].ControlSource = "PERS_FNAME"
        .[College].ControlSource = "JOB_DETL_COLL_NAME"
        .[Dept Name].ControlSource = "JOB_DETL_DEPT_NAME"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is update the displayed information based on the entered record ID, rather than change the Control Source since it is already set.  Try running a `Me.Requery`.

One Problem I can see with your record source statement is that you have included the where condition within the quotes instead of outside.  What this means is that your query is going to look for the value of `ID = [Forms]![form A]![ID]` instead of the value returned from that text box.

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT PERS_LNAME, PERS_FNAME, JOB_DETL_COLL_NAME, " & _
     "JOB_DETL_DEPT_NAME   FROM [main table] where ID = " & [Forms]![form A]![ID]
```

Comment: I'm confused. How will requery help me? All I'm trying to do is query a table and get the fields into the bounded form. Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: Can you please show it in the code? I don't now what to requery. I'm sorry, I'm new with access

Comment: @amirshadaab updated slightly.  Is your form starting out with a record source when you open it and if so could you please provide what the initial record source is and what the fields start out bound to>